# C++ operator == and implicit conversion resolution

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

If I have a `struct A` defined as:

```
struct A {
    const char *data;
    operator const char * () const { return data; }
    friend bool operator== (const A &s1, const char *s2)
    { return /* typical string comparison result */; }
};
```

And I write `A{"hello"} == "test2"`, is `A::operator==` called? What in the standard states that (and why isn't the `A` implicitly converted to `const char *`?)

What about `"test2" == A{"hello"}`? Is the `A` converted in this case?

**EDIT**: What about if `struct A` also has member:

```
friend bool operator== (const char *s1, const A &s2)
```

Comment: just use std::string

Comment: @Davidbrcz That's not what this question is about at all.

Comment: I thought `friend` makes the function **non**-member (i.e., global).

Comment: I edited the title, changing "implicit cast" to "implicit conversion". There is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is an explicit conversion operator.

Comment: @Gill Bates, _It is_. Using a `std::string` would nullify his original request, because even if `operator==` for `std::strings` were to be picked from `A->std::string` conversion, It would work flawlessly. Here, symmetry is broken, which is nasty source of bug especially because 2 string literals may or may not have the same address. It is completely left to the implementation... Classical XY problem !

Comment: @Davidbrcz You're changing the question, he asked "What in the standard states that (and why isn't the A implicitly converted to const char *?)" Not "Should I use std::string rather than const char*?". Your explanation is the same as someone asking why an array does x instead of y and you answer "just use a std::vector". It doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @Gill Bates He is asking the wrong question because he is writing some bad code. Giving him the good solution to his _actual_ problem is always the good thing to do.

Comment: @Davidbrcz I understand what you're trying to say/do, but this isn't the case. I'm bound by the [library](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTString.html). Consider it as an academic question then. And please don't say to convert to and from `std::string`, as that would also be disastrous, in my case.

Comment: @barakmanos It does (at least I'm counting on that). But it doesn't mean you can't write it in-class. My g++ compiled similar code just fine. Note the 2 arguments, and also that you can't add `static` to declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
A{"hello"} == "test2"
```

we perform overload resolution on `operator==`. First, we find the viable candidates ([over.match.viable]), via name lookup:

```
operator==(A const&, const char*);    // yours
operator==(const char*, const char*); // built-in
```

Next, we determine which candidate has the best implicit conversion sequence. This is the first tiebreaker in [over.match.best]:

> Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a *better* function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments *i*, ICS<sub>i</sub>(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICS<sub>i</sub>(F2), and then
>   (1.3) — for some argument *j*, ICS<sub>j</sub>(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICS<sub>j</sub>(F2), or, if not that, [...]

Both operators are Exact Match on the 2nd argument. On the first argument, your `operator==` is an Exact Match whereas the built-in requires a user-defined conversion. Exact Match is the best kind of conversion, and user-defined is the worst - hence, yours has the better conversion sequence and becomes the best viable function.

In broader terms, the `A` isn't implicitly converted to a `const char*` because there's a better option where it doesn't have to be.

---

When you do:

```
"test2" == A{"hello"};
```

Your candidate isn't viable - there is no implicit conversion from `const char*` to `A const&` (first argument), so the only viable candidate is the built-in comparison for `const char*`, which requires the user-defined conversion from `A` to `const char*`.

If you'd like your `A::operator==` to be invoked, you'd have to add a new overload for `operator==(const char*, A const&)`.

Comment: I think OP was after the relevant part in the standard that decided what and why it happens here.

Comment: Just to be clear: in second case, if I had `A::A(const char *s) {}`, then effectively `A("test") == A{"hello"}` would be called? or is it required to be implicit conversion?

Comment: @GillBates Yes I was, so I could know all the other cases I didn't think of just now. I think they would in the same set of rules. Maybe I should clarify question?

Comment: @GillBates Sure, though there are a lot of relevant parts in the standard.

Comment: @Olivetree I don't know what you're asking with regards to the constructor.

Comment: @Barry As for myself, is there some list in the standard that lists the best -> worst "kind of conversions"?

Comment: @Barry you stated "there is no implicit conversion from `const char*` to `A const&`". I was asking if having the `A::A(const char *s) {}` constructor would qualify as such implicit conversion.

Comment: @GillBates [\[over.ics.rank\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank), though you'll also want to look at [\[over.best.ics\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics).

Comment: @Olivetree Yes, it would. That constructor would make `operator==(A const&, const char* )` *viable* for `"hi" == A{"hello"}`... but the builtin would still be a better match.